# My app takes a long time from going from one activity to another

Tags: android, performance, android-layout, android-studio

I'm making an app for my school election and when I press the start screen on the front page it takes about 5 seconds of my continuously pressing to go the next page,and the same applies to every other page how do I fix this?

This is my code:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
public void goMain (View v) {
    Button mainPage = (Button) findViewById(R.id.mainPage);
    mainPage.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, Main2Activity.class);
            startActivity(intent);
        }
    });
}
    public void theFinal (View viewOne){
        ImageButton resultClick = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.resultClick);
        resultClick.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, Results.class);
                startActivity(intent);
            }
        });

    }
```

And the rest of the activites have vote buttons which take it the next activity like this :

```
package com.example.saisriram.studentelections;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.Window;
import android.widget.Button;

public class Main2Activity extends Activity {

int firstHb;
int secHb;
public void hbOne (View v){
    Button hbUno = (Button) findViewById(R.id.hbUno);
    hbUno.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            firstHb = firstHb + 1;
            Intent intent = new 
    Intent(Main2Activity.this,Main3Activity.class);

            startActivity(intent);
        }
    });

}
public void hbTwo (View the){
    Button hbDuo = (Button) findViewById(R.id.hbDuo);
    hbDuo.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            secHb = secHb + 1;
            Intent intent = new Intent(Main2Activity.this,Main3Activity.class);
            startActivity(intent);
        }
    });
}


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    this.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main2);
 }
}
```

Comment: Use "Android Profiler" to find the problem. https://developer.android.com/studio/profile/android-profiler

Comment: Which activity is slow when it opens? Results? The code you are showing only sets click listeners, is that it? that's the only thing your activity does? Also can you post Results acitviity

Comment: No I havent finished making the results activity ,cause I wanna finish all the basic things first.And all of them are slow everytime a button is pressed it takes a few seconds and a few presses to go to the next page and I dont know why it just says the application may be doing too much work on its main thread

Comment: where is the oncreate methods? are you not showing all of your code? whats the manifest look like?

Comment: Are you running this on an emulator?  There is a good chance that the combination of debug mode, plus the emulator, plus the machine that you are running on may be causing it to be slow.  For a sanity check, i'd recommend running this on a real device in release mode.  Install it on your device.  Run it from there and see if you are still feeling the delay.

Comment: Kyle ,I I downloaded the apk and tried it on a real device it was still slow

Comment: DroiDev I wrote the code in the mainactivity not the oncreate is that the mistake?

Answer (score 0):

If loading activity is taking longer time then surely you are doing some long operation in activity life cycle methods.OnResume() executed means , UI is visible to user completely and its intractable now. But seems you are doing some heavy operation before onResume() finishes. Move long operations in worker thread to make UI loading smooth.

Comment: But I showed you my code,im not doing heavy operations Im just incrementing variables and going to the next activity,so why is it not smooth?

Answer (score 0):

Are you running this on an emulator?  There is a good chance that the combination of debug mode, plus the emulator, plus the machine that you are running on may be causing it to be slow.  For a sanity check, i'd recommend running this on a real device in release mode.  Install it on your device.  Run it from there and see if you are still feeling the delay.  If that fixes it, its probably your development machine + emulator causing issue.  If it doesn't, i'd second looking into Android Profiler to get a better idea on the memory consumed.

Comment: Ive run it on a real device aswell and the problem is still there,and Ive used the android profiling Im not sure how to really fix anyth with that please help